# Why does my SELECT return only a subset of the rows?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working with an Oracle database for the first time and stumbled upon another problem again. When I want to select all the rows in a table with some `JOINS` I only get the first 350 rows of about 15.000 rows.

Anyone know if there is a set limit somewhere I'm not aware of?

Below is my query if needed:

```
SELECT orders.plant, orders.workcenter, workcenters.occupied,
       workcenters.section, workcentersections.section, orders.capacitycat,
       orders.week, orders.earlieststartdate, orders.lateststartdate,
       orders.useropstatus, orders.programstatus, orders.reqhours,
       orders.finishdate, orders.reqquantity, orders.material, parts.TYPE,
       parttypes.TYPE, orders.ordernumber, orders.operation,
       orders.preoperation, orders.seqoperation, orders.projectcode,
       orders.queuetime, orders.hoursworked, orders.operationtext,
       orders.shorttext
  FROM (((orders INNER JOIN workcenters ON orders.workcenter =
                                                              workcenters.code)
       INNER JOIN
       workcentersections ON workcenters.section = workcentersections.ID)
       INNER JOIN
       parts ON orders.material = parts.material)
       INNER JOIN
       parttypes ON parts.TYPE = parttypes.ID
```

Comment: Which client do you use to execute the query and fetch the results>

Comment: How do you know that the result should be 15000 rows? Do you have any `NULL` values in your foreign keys?

Comment: Debug it by commenting out joins and then run it while subsequently commenting in each join. Then you'll easily find which join does something you obviously do not expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your ORDERS table contains 15000 rows and your original query returns only 350 rows, you can replace your (INNER) JOINs with OUTER JOINs:

```
SELECT orders.plant, orders.workcenter, workcenters.occupied,
       workcenters.section, workcentersections.section, orders.capacitycat,
       orders.week, orders.earlieststartdate, orders.lateststartdate,
       orders.useropstatus, orders.programstatus, orders.reqhours,
       orders.finishdate, orders.reqquantity, orders.material, parts.TYPE,
       parttypes.TYPE, orders.ordernumber, orders.operation,
       orders.preoperation, orders.seqoperation, orders.projectcode,
       orders.queuetime, orders.hoursworked, orders.operationtext,
       orders.shorttext
  FROM orders
       LEFT OUTER JOIN workcenters ON orders.workcenter = workcenters.code
       LEFT OUTER JOIN workcentersections 
            ON workcenters.section = workcentersections.ID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN parts ON orders.material = parts.material
       LEFT OUTER JOIN parttypes ON parts.TYPE = parttypes.ID
```

This will give you all rows from ORDERS (you might get duplicates if you haven't got strict 1:N relationships).

Then, you should replace the LEFT OUTER JOINs one-by-one with INNER JOINs and check the row count of each of these modified queries to find out which of the JOINs is responsible for the missing data.